# Maze representation help

Tags: c++, maze

I want to create maze using graph but I don't know where to start. I just know ways to represent a maze that use array of array or graph.

1. In Array of Array representation, is recursive backtracking used to generate maze?
2. If I choose to use graph-based struct to generate the maze, then how do I map edges representing path? What I mean is how to create walls that are represented by end node of a graph?

Comment: A graph will basically only be representing the topological information in the maze; i.e. nodes represent junctions, and edges represent paths between the junctions.  I don't know how walls would fit into this.

Comment: I'd also choose a graph/node based approach.- Walls would simply be implicitly defined where there is no connection.

Comment: What are you going to use the maze for?

Comment: @moka: Yes, if you have a graph node for every cell in the maze.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Thinking Labyrinth](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm) -- All you never thought you'd want to know about mazes. In addition to helping you identify terms for further research, this website is an extensive resource in itself.

Comment: Wow! I've lost already some minutes of my life! More are coming!

Comment: I'd +10 if I could, that link is a gold mine!